# Как поймать исключение и показать alert dialog

Tags: java, android, sqlite

**Дано:** диалоговое окно, при нажатии на которое появляется ошибка `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed` (что это за ошибка и почему появляется я знаю)

**Нужно:** поймать это исключение и вывести сообщение (другое диалоговое окно "Запись уже существует!")

**Вопрос:** как это реализовать? на сколько я понял, блок `catch` не срабатывает, т.к. в `логе` не покавывает мое сообщение

**Важно:** чтоб при нажатии кнопки ОК первое диалоговое окно не закрылось, если появилась ошибка

```
private void showAddArticleDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_article_dialog, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText edt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);

    String title = "";
    //String message = "Enter text below";

    if(TYPE){
        title = getString(R.string.title_add_income_article);
    }else{
        title = getString(R.string.title_add_cost_article);
    }
    dialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
    //dialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            try {
                myDb.addCategory(edt.getText().toString(), R.drawable.star, TYPE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //showLog(getString(R.string.this_article_exists));
                Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString() + " ------- " + R.string.this_article_exists);
            }
            initializeAdapter();

        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //pass
        }
    });
    AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
    b.show();
}
```

*Вот лог:*

```
02-28 12:28:04.891 23792-23792/ru.by_em.my_finances E/SQLiteLog: (2067) abort at 17 in [INSERT INTO direction(category_name,category_photo,_id) VALUES (?,?,?)]: UNIQUE constraint failed: direction.category_name
02-28 12:28:04.896 23792-23792/ru.by_em.my_finances E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting category_name=Обеды category_photo=2130837652 _id=13
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: direction.category_name (code 2067)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:952)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1595)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1465)
at ru.by_em.my_finances.db.DBDataSource.addCategory(DBDataSource.java:241)
at ru.by_em.my_finances.activities.ChangeArticlesActivity$1.onClick(ChangeArticlesActivity.java:100)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:161)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`catch` не работает потому что исключение перехватывается в `SQLite` и просто пишется в лог.

Попробуйте метод для вставки `insertOrThrow` или `insertWithOnConflict` с алгоритмом `SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_FAIL`. Тогда `Exception` пробросится до Вашего `catch`

Подробнее:
[тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)) и 
[тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#CONFLICT_FAIL)

Comment: Спасибо больше помогли, теперь в catch попал, но как сделать так чтобы моё диалоговое окно не закрывалось, когда сработал  catch

Comment: [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086848/android-dont-dismiss-alertdialog-after-clicking-positivebutton) есть ответ

Comment: Спасибо, помогли)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в catch блоке вы перехватываете не тот тип исключения.
Например используете java.sql.SQLException вместо android.database.SQLException.

Судя по логу у вас происходит android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException исключение.
Можно перехватывать в catch непосредственно его SQLiteConstraintException, либо соответственно одно из супер исключений:

- android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
- android.database.SQLException
- java.lang.RuntimeException
- java.lang.Exception.

Попробуйте так:

```
} catch (android.database.SQLException e)
```

либо так:

```
} catch (SQLiteConstraintException e)
```

либо так:

```
} catch (Exception e)
```

Comment: не помогло, я пробовал тока кроме android.database.SQLException e, но ничего не помогло